# Two people roll a single six-sided fair die, each. $A$ rolls then $B$ rolls. The person with the higher number rolled wins (no one wins with a tie).

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Two people roll a single six-sided fair die, each. $A$ rolls then $B$ rolls. The person with the higher number rolled wins (no one wins with a tie). What is the probability that $A$ wins? That $B$ wins? That neither wins?

I think I have to solve the problem using a system of equations and add up the probabilities at the end but I am not sure if that is the right idea. I just do not understand how to use this to solve the problem.

Comment: I upvoted 
Jorge Fernández Hidalgo's answer and advise that you read it carefully, with respect to the following *thought experiment*.  Suppose that A and B are both blindfolded by a 3rd person (i.e. a moderator) **and then** they roll, with A using a red die and B using a green die.  Once both rolls are made, the blindfolds are removed.  Intuitively: (1) Is this scenario mathematically equivalent to the original problem? ...see next comment

Comment: (2) When the red and green dice are simultaneously inspected (i.e. A and B simultaneously remove their blindfolds), are the *probable outcomes* of the red and green dice rolls **mathematically affected** by who rolled first?

Answer (score 4):

The probability that they tie is $\frac{1}{6}$ because no matter what the first person gets the second person has a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance of getting that number. The probability that $A$ wins is the same as the probability that $B$ wins. Therefore it is equal to $$\frac{1 - \frac{1}{6} }{2} = \frac{5}{12}$$